# System Scope Jar Throws Class Not Found Exception

Tags: java, maven, javafx, classnotfoundexception

My project uses javafx jar and includes it through system scope in maven. It works fine in my local. Now, since the jar is included through system scope, it is not included in the fat jar and when, I deploy that fat jar, it is giving ClassNotFound Exception for javafx class. Why is it not able to access that javafx jar on the machine where I deployed the project, since, the javafx is located in the same lib folder in that machine also?

PS: I manually copied javafx jar to that machine on the JAVA_HOME/lib/ folder.

Update: Just noticed that running the jar from the local itself, is throwing that error, though running fine from eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

There could be a number of reasons why this is occurring:

1.)  When you copied in the javafx jar, the permissions are wrong so that it is not readable by the process running your java program.

2.)  The user that is running your java program does not have the JAVA_HOME/lib folder on the classpath.  This can happen if you run your program as say a service-level user, but installed java as another user.  Sometimes the JAVA_HOME may not be set for the other user in their profile.

3.)  Different versions of your target jar may move classes around, such that running with version 1.0 will work, but 2.0 will result in a class not found exception because the class has been moved to a new package.  Make sure you are have the same version of the javafx jar in both places.